# How does Chrome decide if a site only supports flash?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

According to Google, [as of Chrome 55](https://blog.google/products/chrome/flash-and-chrome/), Flash is disabled for sites unless they "only support flash." But, I don't see any explanation of what that means exactly.

We have a *lot* of legacy flash content. And, for the most part, we can host that content in a pretty thin wrapper. But, the DOM clearly doesn't consist *only* of an `embed` or `object` tag. It has a `title`, a `div` container for positioning, perhaps some analytics, etc..

At what point, from a technical perspective, does it transition from/to being "only" flash with respect to Chrome 55 and 56+?

---

Our current situation is that our new, thin wrapper "works for me." But, "works for me" is not an acceptable response to customer complaints. Until our very lengthy flash conversion project is done (1 to 2 years from now), we need to know where the technical line in the sand is.

If there's something official from Google or line in the Chromium source that makes it clear, that would be ideal.

Comment: Nice move... Down vote an Answer then change the original Question. What have you tried? What's the minimum way to recreate your issue? Got a link that demo's the said "works for me" issue? Why not ask on Google forums where actual Chrome staff answer questions too? Notice I didn't even down vote your **close**-able `Why isn't this working...` question?

Comment: It's not a "why isn't this working" question. It's a question that anyone who contributes to the Chromium source could probably answer definitively.

Comment: PS: If it works for you... best share examples of a typical "customer complaint" since that may give more clue to fixing real issue. You can't ask anyone how to fix something mysterious (no link/code) that also works perfectly fine for you.

Comment: PPS: Then only the Chromium forums are your best bet for a faster Answer. What did your customer(s) say is wrong for them..?

Comment: @VC.One After chatting with more of our QA folks, it may not ultimately matter. Our solution *seems* to at least be prompting some of them now to "run the plugin." (Or whatever.) Previously, the SWF's were placed directly in an `iframe` (no idea why) ... *Some* Chrome users were reporting that the SWF assets were simply downloading, rather than showing in the frame...

Comment: ... I'm leaving this question open for now though. There *is* a technical answer. The rule is written in code, after all. Somebody must know where to find it!

Comment: Now that's useful info towards a solution, just a couple more... The `iframe` URL was a direct link to the SWF? Are you hosting the SWF from same domain/folder as page html? PS: What is the display size of your SWF?

Answer (score 1):

after chrome version 55+, chrome prefer html5 over flash by default.

Before 55 version, client easily deactive/ active flash plugin by chrome://plugins. Unfortunately this removed. Also chrome changes the plugin list api. Before 55 version, we can check flash is in plugin list or not , now we can not check the plugin exist . About one year, chrome keeps supporting flash, but it will perefer html5 if your player support html5 too ( ie : rtmp for flash, hls or mpegdash for html5 )
chrome://flags/#prefer-html-over-flash
here it shows that html over flash is default ( default is active ).

Also chrome generate a module that 
chrome://site-engagement/

Here is a rank about website, you can update the value, if 100% , flash automatically chosen. Otherwise flash is blocked.

For more details 
read this presentation.

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/106_KLNJfwb9L-1hVVa4i29aw1YXUy9qFX-Ye4kvJj-4/edit#slide=id.p